# How do I set a .java program in startup in a Raspberry PI?

Tags: java, linux, startup, raspberry-pi3

I've tried searching for other answers on the web, but I haven't found a working solution yet.
I have a .java application (developed  with NetBeans 8.2) and I want to set it to start when my PI boots up.

Comment: Well, do you know how to run a Java program? Do you know how to run a program on start-up in a Raspberry Pi? Those are two separate concerns, but once you know both of them, you can do what you're looking for. If you're unsure of one of them, that's the thing to research.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a java program and executing a command on startup are two different concerns, but you can write a script that executes your java program and tell Linux to load it on startup.

---

CD to the PI folder.

```
cd ~
```

Create a script that runs your java program:

```
sudo nano runjava
java <your program and arguments>
```

Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now open up `.bashrc` to configure the startup:

```
sudo nano .bashrc
```

And add this to the bottom of the file.

```
./runjava
```

Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This would run the program every time you log in.

**P.S.**: You might need to provide `+x` permission on the script (`chmod`).

[Reference](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8735/48056)